# creating a browse button in web page in c#

Tags: c#

I have created a web page and in it I have created a browse button with name "BrowseButton" and a textbox with name "BrowseTextBox"

The backend code is:

```
protected void BrowseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            BrowseTextBox.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
```

but I am getting a `ThreadStateException` and I don't know how to handle it....

Comment: sorry this line is comment-

Comment: FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog

Comment: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.

Comment: are you using asp.net?

Comment: but i dont have main in it

Comment: @rajnivk you can't use winforms components in a web browser.

Comment: You might be looking for file upload control..http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

Answer (score 3):

You say that you are creating a web page, but your code uses the `OpenFileDialog` class from either the Windows Forms or WPF library.  These dialogs can't be used on a web application - they're for use when writing Windows applications.  The threading error you're seeing is a direct consequence of this.

You can't do anything about this exception: there's no way to use those classes in a web app.  Instead, if you want to upload a file, you should perhaps look at the `<input type="file"` element of HTML, or perhaps the [`FileUpload` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) in ASP.NET.

Comment: @rajnivk: I would suggest that you follow the link that I've (very helpfully) included in my answer, and see what it says.  There are four examples on that page.  Then, if you are still having issues, you should post a new question with the specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work since the only way the `FolderBrowserDialog` would pop-up is `Server-Side` so the program would wait forever for an input.

You should use [this **Web Control**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) that suits your needs better.

**From the MSDN Exmple**

```
 protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save the uploaded file to an "Uploads" directory
    // that already exists in the file system of the 
    // currently executing ASP.NET application.  
    // Creating an "Uploads" directory isolates uploaded 
    // files in a separate directory. This helps prevent
    // users from overwriting existing application files by
    // uploading files with names like "Web.config".
    string saveDir = @"\Uploads\";

    // Get the physical file system path for the currently
    // executing application.
    string appPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;

    // Before attempting to save the file, verify
    // that the FileUpload control contains a file.
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string savePath = appPath + saveDir +
            Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName);

        // Call the SaveAs method to save the 
        // uploaded file to the specified path.
        // This example does not perform all
        // the necessary error checking.               
        // If a file with the same name
        // already exists in the specified path,  
        // the uploaded file overwrites it.
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);

        // Notify the user that the file was uploaded successfully.
        UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Your file was uploaded successfully.";

    }
    else
    {
        // Notify the user that a file was not uploaded.
        UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";   
    }
```

I don't think I can explain it better than they did...

Comment: so what should i do? pls help

Comment: Well first of all, why do you want to upload a folder to your web page ? Do you really want to upload it or you just need the name of the file ?

Comment: i want it for both purposes

Comment: i am sorry for asking these naive questions but i dont know much about c# and i want this work urgently